# getting 404 Not Found error : nginx no error; i could restart nginx server and start pm2 of my node application

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, pm2

my application was running correctly and was ssl secured, running with below code.

Today, I renewed ssl certificate with godaddy and the domain is secured. I could start nginx successfully with the sites_available/default below code. But my application is not showing up and getting 404 Not Found error.

I get error with mydomain.de and also the same not found error using ip address to access my application too.

Could anyone check this please and let me know what's the problem?

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;      
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
    
upstream mydomain.de
       {
      server 127.0.0.1:8080;
      }

server {
    listen 443 ssl;     
    server_name mydomain.de;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/mydomain.de.chained.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/pem_with_key.key;

    root /var/www/html;    
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    
    server_name _;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.

        #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

            proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                proxy_connect_timeout 3600;
                proxy_send_timeout 3600;
                proxy_read_timeout 3600;
                send_timeout 36000s;
               
               # proxy_redirect http://locahost:8080 https://mydomain.de;
                
        #proxy_hide_header X-Frame-Options;
#add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
#add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
#add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains";

}
}
```

Comment: before checking nginx -t successful or not, by mistake i restarted the nginx service. Do you think this would have created an issue?

Comment: my pm2 process id was 0.. by mistake forcefully i added another process id 1.. and deleted 0. Is that the reason my application gets 404 error.. but how could i create another process with id 0?